# GCD\GCF\HCF in Java

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I have a little problem with my code:

```
public static int ggT(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;
    if (a == b)
        result = a;
    else if ( a > b)
        a -= b;
        result = a % b;
    if (b > a)
        b -= a;
        result = a % b;
    return result;
}
```

The first if case works perfectly! But the other two if cases won't work(they always return 0 as a result.
And I have no clue why... :/
Would be great if somebody could help or explain where I have been making mistakes.
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Use `{` and `}` to group instructions.

Comment: If you don't use `{ ... }` for `if` statements in Java (also for other things like loops), Java will only consider the **first statement** after the `if` condition belonging to the `if` case. So your `result = ...` statements are actually **not part** of the case. If you want to include them, add curly braces to group the statements.

Comment: Can you give some sample inputs and expected outputs?

Answer (score 0):

based on your indentation, it looks like you need to put some parenthesis around your statements

```
public static int ggT(int a, int b) {
    int result = 0;
    if (a == b) {
        result = a;
    } else if ( a > b) {
        a -= b;
        result = a % b;
    }
    if (b > a) {
        b -= a;
        result = a % b;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you're not using parentheses, only the first line after the 'if' is considered part of the statement. the 'return' is is always executed

Comment: also it is possible to run through case 2 and 3. Shouldn't it be an else if, too? a direct return in each cae would be even better.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. I added the parentheses and still get a wrong result/always returns 0 as result. :/ Any other suggestions what could gone wrong? =D

Answer (score 0):

1) You have to add parentheses in if conditions.
2) Last if condition should replace with else if condition.

Check below code:

```
public static int ggT(int a, int b) {
        int result = 0;
        if (a == b){
            result = a;
        } else if ( a > b){
            a -= b;
        } else if (b > a){
            b -= a;
        }

        if(a > b) {    //Check 
            result = b % a; 
        } else if(b > a){
            result = a % b;
        } else if(b == a){
            result = a;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a GCD algorithm

1) It shouldn't be that complex

2) It should be recursive. You can't calculate a gcd in a single step.

Assuming a and b are non-negative, it can be a simple as

```
int gcd(int a, int b) {
   if(b==0) {
     return a;
   }
   return gcd(b, a % b);
}
```